# Matplotlib error while coloring barplot with list

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Let's say I did 16 experiments replicated 3 times for a total of 48 measures.
Here's an example of my dataframe and a snippet that replicates my problem:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.abs(np.random.randn(48, 4)), columns=list("ABCD"))

color_list = plt.cm.gnuplot(np.linspace(0,1,16))

df.A.plot.bar( figsize=(16,7), color=color_list)
plt.axvline(15.5, c="black", lw=1)
plt.axvline(31.5, c="black", lw=1)
plt.plot()
```

And here's the output of the graph:

[image: Problematic Barplot]

So, the vertical lines represents each replica, there is 16 bars in each. My color list is also of length 16 so I would expect to have 3 times the same colors, but at 16 and 17, there is two black bars (which is the 0th color in the list) and at 32, there is this yellow bar that comes from the offset caused by the second black line at 17. Followed by 2 black lines again.

It looks like my `color_list` puts a 0 automatically when it starts for the second time.

**Edit** : My temporary solution was to create a list of length 48 that is the first list repeated 3 times:

```
lst=list(np.linspace(0,1,16))
liste = lst + lst + lst
color_list = plt.cm.gnuplot(liste)
```

Comment: It seems this comes from pandas, using matplotlib along doesn't have such problem.

Comment: Can you paste the line of code you used to give the same graph with only matplotlib ?

Comment: You can use `plt.figure(figsize=(16,7))
plt.bar(range(len(df.A)), df.A, color=color_list)` but you will need to tweak the axis and a few other things.

Comment: I've created a PR to pandas to fix the bug as well. You can use that one if you wish. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/20727